# Voltaire's recommendation to Katharina II

Tags: history-of-philosophy

In a letter to tsarina Katharina II, Voltaire recommended to persecute Muslims. One of his reasons was that they imprison their wifes. What were his further reasons? (I heard this in an audio biography and have no access to the extended correspondence between Voltaire and Katharina.)

Comment: See also Voltaire's play: [Le fanatisme, ou Mahomet le Prophète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahomet_(play)) for V's attitude towards Muslims.

Comment: Maybe useful (but in French): Djavâd Hadidi, [Voltaire et l'Islam](https://books.google.it/books/about/Voltaire_et_l_Islam.html?id=q7-iTWGKn-cC&redir_esc=y&hl=it) (1974).

Comment: See also on-line: [Recension – Les textes de Voltaire sur l’Islam](http://www.implications-philosophiques.org/recensions/recension-voltaire-sur-lislam/).

Comment: You can see also *Dictionnaire philosophique*'s entry on [Alcoran](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_philosophique/Garnier_(1878)/Alcoran).

Answer (score 1):

A famous encyclopedia was written around the time of Voltaire, edited by fellow French Enlightenment thinkers Diderot and D'Alembert - and crucial to the development of the Enlightenment project and later critical to the ideas of the French Revolutionaries. You may get an idea of how Muslims were generally viewed by the intelligentsia of the time from the encyclopedia page on "Mohammedanism", which might help provide some context to Voltaire's thoughts:

https://quod.lib.umich.edu/d/did/did2222.0000.439/--mohammedanism?rgn=main;view=fulltext#idno_did2222.0000.439

Comment: This answer is useful but not quoting Voltair's arguments.

Comment: Voltaire contributed articles to the Encyclopedia beginning with Vol. 5. (Ref: SEP).